# SQL Top and Join

Tags: sql, join, sap-ase

**Business Rule**:  We can only bill for followup events every 90 days. Any events that occur less than 90 days after the previous one cannot be billed, but they need to be recorded.

**User requirement**:  They want to see the date the last event bill was submitted on the tab where they would submit the bill for the current event, to have a visual cue as to whether submitting a bill is worth doing.

Events have an event_id and an event_date in table event. Event_id is a foreign key in table event_bill, which has the submitted_date for the bill.
Events have a foreign key customer_id, for each customer, so a customer can have multiple events in any time period.

Given the current event_id and the customer_id, I'm trying to get the submitted_date for the most recent previous event.

Here's what I've tried:

```
    SELECT TOP 1 (event_id) as prev_event_id
    INTO #tmp
    FROM  event 
    WHERE customer_id = @custID
    AND event_type = 'Followup'
    AND event_id < @eventID 
    ORDER BY event_date DESC

    SELECT eb.submitted_date
    FROM event_bill eb
    JOIN #tmp
    ON eb.event_id = #tmp.prev_event_id

    DROP TABLE #tmp
```

This would be all well and good, but my application's database permissions don't allow for the creation of the temp table.

In an attempt without the temp table, I got errors that I can't use the ORDER BY in a derived table, but I need that to make sure I get the last event before the current one for this customer:

```
    SELECT eb.submitted_date
    FROM event_bill eb
    JOIN
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 (event_id) as prev_event_id
    FROM  event 
    WHERE customer_id = @custID
    AND event_type = 'Followup'
    AND event_id < @eventID 
    ORDER BY event_date DESC
    ) x
    ON eb.event_id = x.prev_event_id
```

Could anyone give me a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will help you

```
 SELECT eb.submitted_date
    FROM event_bill eb
    JOIN
    (
    SELECT event_id as prev_event_id
    FROM  event 
    WHERE customer_id = @custID
    AND event_type = 'Followup'
    AND event_id < @eventID 
    and event_date = 
    (
      select max(event_date)
      FROM  event 
      WHERE customer_id = @custID
      AND event_type = 'Followup'
      AND event_id < @eventID 
    )
    ) x
    ON eb.event_id = x.prev_event_id
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!  Now that I see this written out, it makes more sense that I just had to rejoin the event table on itself again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
SELECT eb.submitted_date
FROM event_bill eb
WHERE
  eb.event_id IN (
    SELECT event.event_id 
    FROM event 
    WHERE 
      event.customer_id = @custID 
      AND event.event_type = 'Followup'
      AND event.event_id < @eventID
    ORDER BY event_date DESC
     LIMIT 1
   )
```

Comment: It's sybase-ase, there is no option 'limit 1'

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the ORDER BY would be accepted with the top.  If not, you can do this:

```
 SELECT eb.submitted_date
 FROM event_bill eb JOIN
      event e
      on eb.event_id = e.event_id join
      (SELECT customer_id, MAX(eventdate) as maxdate
       FROM  event
       WHERE customer_id = @custID AND
            event_type = 'Followup' AND
            event_id < @eventID
       group by customer_id
      ) md
     ON e.customer_id = md.customer_id and
        eb.event_date = md.maxdate
```

This calculates the maxdate and then uses this for the join.

Comment: The problem with this one is that the customer ID and event_date are only in event, and event_bill only has event_id and submitted_date, which is different than event_date.